# echo copyfile.txt | pbcopy ....and then paste one line at a time?

Tags: unix, command-line, copy-paste

I have a multi-line text file. 
lets call it 26 lines.

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

You get the idea...

Is there a unix command I can use to add all of the files' content into my paste-bar, but then only paste the content one line at a time?

for example.

I would like to `echo copyfile.txt | pbcopy` ( or whatever the command is )
and then click paste once to paste

```
A
```

and then the next time I click paste my computer prints

```
B
```

and then the next time I hit paste my computer prints

```
C
```

and so on and so on.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made an alias in my ~/.bash_profile as follows:

```
alias k='head -1 cutpaste.txt | pbcopy
echo "$(tail -n +2 cutpaste.txt)" > cutpaste.txt'
```

The first command grabs the first line of the file, and then the second command deletes the first line of the file.

very precise, but a little more tedious than I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

The below script does not load all the file content into clipboard in a single shot but may achieve your need. Using xclip command

```
for line in `cat filename`
do
echo $line | xclip -selection clipboard
read -p "Press Paste : "
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your attempt, however this didn't work for me. 
all this did was put the entire contents of the file into my paste-bar.  I will read up on the xclip command to see if I can elaborate on this script.

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is sort of close

```
for line in `cat ~/Desktop/paste.txt`
> do
> echo $line | pbcopy
> sleep 2
> echo $line | pbcopy
> done
```

except for it's very easy to skip a line or two, if you don't paste it within the two seconds, so its not perfect.

instead of `sleep 2` is there a different command that could be used?